# How to add custom components to Eclipse swing palette?

Tags: eclipse, swing, windowbuilder, jcalendar

I downloaded the Jcalendar API and added it to my projects library and build path as usual but now I would also like to add it to the swing palette for more convenience. I know it's possible with netbeans and I'm pretty sure you can do it with Eclipse and WindowBuilder Pro also, I just can't find anywhere how to.

Comment: then add your answer as an answer and accept it when possible. You should have also mentioned which plugin you are using for building the GUI. WindowBuilder Pro I guess? You should also add the appropriate tag.

Comment: okok, well I can't answer my own question on the same day since I don't have enough reputation. WindowBuilder yes - tag added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually figured the problem out myself. Just right-click on the swing palette, then choose Palette Manager and from there you can import jar files and add them to the palette!

Comment: Been looking for how to do this for aaages. Thanks